# Data Sorting method for TCP server

Tags: sorting, unity-game-engine, floating-point, logic, tcpclient

I'm currently having a working TCP connection between Unity(Client) and an Android App(Server). Unity handles the task to send my controller joysticks data to the Server.

I have 2 joysticks on my controller and both of them return Vector2 output(x,y) (in total, I will receive 4 float values if I use both at the same time)

My current method is to individually parse them into a byte array and send each of them to the Server (Below is my code to send the left joy x and y values from the Client to the Server)

```
            float fData_Lx = LeftJoy.GetAxis(SteamVR_Input_Sources.Any).x;
            float fData_Ly = LeftJoy.GetAxis(SteamVR_Input_Sources.Any).y;               
            byte[] clientMessageAsByteArray_1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(fData_Lx);
            byte[] clientMessageAsByteArray_2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(fData_Ly);
            Array.Reverse(clientMessageAsByteArray_1); // Flip - Reverse from little Endian to Big Endian (C# -> Java)
            Array.Reverse(clientMessageAsByteArray_2);
            // Write byte array to socketConnection stream.
            stream.Write(clientMessageAsByteArray_1, 0, clientMessageAsByteArray_1.Length);
            stream.Write(clientMessageAsByteArray_2, 0, clientMessageAsByteArray_2.Length);
```

Server code to receive the data:

```
            in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
            in.read(cData);
            float f = ByteBuffer.wrap(cData).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getFloat(); //Use to read single Data
            System.out.println("Data: " + f);
```

Therefore, the Server will receive 2 floats at the same time and it won't know which float is the x and which float is the y.

I want to ask if there is a solution to sort these floats at the Server side so that it can understand these float values. I'm planning to send 4 floats at the same time as I gonna use both of my joysticks.
Really appreciate your help (Please don't be mad at me, I know my logic to receive the data is really bad)

Answer (score 0):

> if there is a solution to sort these floats at the Server side so that it can understand these float values

-> No!

The server only knows it received a `byte[]` .. if you wouldn't tell it it is actually a `float` it wouldn't even know that fact.

However this is TCP. So actually you can rely on two facts:

1. Everything that is sent in a certain order is received in the exact same order.
2. There is an individual TCP socket for each of your clients.

These two should be enough to exactly identify your input:

1. simply make sure the server reads not one but rather two consecutive float values (first x then y - that's exactly how your client sends it). As long as you didn't receive both your Input is not valid anyway, so you wait until you definitely received x and y.
2. on server side you already know from which of the existing client sockets you received the data. So once you received the two floats you already know exactly who was the sender of these values and who you have to apply them to on server side.

---

Is there a special reason why you invert the order of the arrays on client side and then tell the server to receive them in BigEndian? Why not simply tell the server to receive LittleEndian and on client side only invert the array within [`if(BitConverter.IsBigEndian)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.islittleendian) ?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm trying to solve the problem follow your suggestions. Really appreciate your help